# Angular 4 not loading component

Tags: angular, angular4-router

I'm trying to use Angular Routes in Angular 4 app, but the app is not able to load the component matching the requested route:

Here is `app-routing.module.ts`:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

`app.module.ts` looks like this:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    DashboardComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
  ],
  providers: [ ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.component.html:

```
<h1>
    Welcome to {{title}}!
</h1>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

My `dashboard.component.html` :

```
<p>dashboard works!</p>
```

I'm trying to figure out whats wrong, also looked at the Angular 4 Routing [tutorial](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt5). Please help.

Comment: import { AppRoutingModule } from './/app-routing.module';
Loot at ".//app.." why two slash?

Comment: This import was added by `ng generate` in app.module.ts. However, it tried after removing one slash, didn't work. The component 'AppComponent' doesn't load.

Comment: What is the error you are getting ?

Comment: I have looked at browser console, it says:
`Error: No base href set. Please provide a value for the APP_BASE_HREF token or add a base element to the document. at new PathLocationStrategy (common.js:647) at provideLocationStrategy (router.js:6995)
at _callFactory (core.js:10651)
at _createProviderInstance$1 (core.js:10599)
    at initNgModule (core.js:10549)
    at new NgModuleRef_ (core.js:11792)
    at createNgModuleRef (core.js:11782)
    at Object.debugCreateNgModuleRef [as createNgModuleRef] (core.js:14092)
    at NgModuleFactory_.create (core.js:15216)
    at eval (core.js:5370)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution after some troubleshooting, and found the answer on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40274540/chrome-extension-no-base-href-set-please-provide-a-value-for-the-app-base-hre). Basically, in `app.module.ts`, we just have to add this import statement for importing `APP_BASE_HREF` token:

```
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
```

And add the `APP_BASE_HREF` to `providers` array:

```
providers: [ {provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/' }],
```

Another solution according to the Angular [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/router#base-href) is to simply add `<base href="/">` as the first child of `<head>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

well, i got the wrong thing

```
exports: [RouterModule]
```

you are exporting a core module from @angular/router so your AppModule get extended by  RouterModule, not your route and instead of creating the whole module just export the const
like

```
export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);
```

and import routing in your appmodule