# Navigate to a component Angular 9

Tags: angular

I have been the whole day trying to figure out how can I load a new page in Angular 9, like when you click, and you can see that you are being redirected to a new page. I have seen the following relevant links, none of which has solved my question:

- [Angular 4 not loading component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47391157/angular-4-not-loading-component)
- https://angular.io/guide/router
- [How to navigate to other page in angular 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51909800/how-to-navigate-to-other-page-in-angular-6/55217592)
- https://www.techiediaries.com/angular-router-routerlink-navigate-navigatebyurl/

I have successfully achieved a not-wanted behavior, in which the components are loaded on the same page instead of on a new page.

This is my `app.module.ts`

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { CreateQueueComponent } from './create-queue/create-queue.component';
import { SubscribeQueueComponent } from './subscribe-queue/subscribe-queue.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { ManageQueueComponent } from './manage-queue/manage-queue.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    CreateQueueComponent,
    SubscribeQueueComponent,
    ManageQueueComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

This is my `app-routing.module.ts`

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { CreateQueueComponent } from './create-queue/create-queue.component';
import { ManageQueueComponent } from './manage-queue/manage-queue.component';
import { SubscribeQueueComponent } from './subscribe-queue/subscribe-queue.component';


const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'createQueue', component: CreateQueueComponent },
  { path: 'manageQueue', component: ManageQueueComponent },
  { path: 'subscribeQueue', component: SubscribeQueueComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

As the documentation suggest, I have made sure in my `index.html` I have the `<base href="/">`

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.8.2/css/bulma.min.css">
  <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/js/all.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my `app.component.html`

```
...
<a class="circle-link option-card" title="Join" routerLink="/subscribeQueue">
   <i class="fas fa-calendar"></i>
   <span>Subscribe</span>
</a>
...
```

My `<router-outlet>` is appended at the end of the `app.component.html`. So the question would be, how can I replace the content or partial content of the web with the one on the target component?

Does anyone know what's going on? Am I missing something here?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you include your code containing the `<router-outlet>`?

Comment: I have updated my question @RMo

Answer (score 1):

The component that is correlated with a route in the `router.module.ts` file will always display in the `<router-outlet>`.

**changing the entire page**

The code below will load a component as the entire page with the router.

*app.component.html*

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**changing part of page with the router**

The code  below will always load the `<h1>Always header</h1>` and additionally load the 
component you are routing to in the `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`.

Your base path `''` does not exist in your `router.module.ts` so the router won't load anything in the `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` on the homepage since there is no component bound to it.

I expect this is what you were doing. I can't tell for sure however since you didn't provide that part of the code.

*app.component.html*

```
<h1>Always header</h1>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of Angular is to build single-page applications.

The role of the `RouterModule` is to make your single page application looks like several pages, even if technically the browser is always on the same page.

It will put the component corresponding to the “current page“ inside: `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` .

Comment: That's what I have done. The question would be now how can I replace the content of the actual page with the new one?