# What is the difference between HTML base href and Angular APP_BASE_HREF?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-router

I'm working on an Angular app where I'm faced with setting an HTML base href value, and/or an APP_BASE_HREF value.

What is the difference and relation between these?

Comment: Not really no. I'm looking for a clear difference between these two things.

Comment: could you accept my answer if it answers your question?

Answer (score 5):

In general, you should only have to set the `<base href>`.

Exceptions are if you do not have access to the `index.html` or you want the HTML5 style URLs to be different from where you are serving the Angular files (then you need to provide the `APP_BASE_HREF`).

> What is the difference and relation between these?

The `<base href>` is used as the default base URL ([see source code](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/b5ab7aff433a67cddaa55e621d17b1a1b07b57c2/packages/common/src/location/location_strategy.ts#L121)) when generating HTML5 style URLs for your web app. Additionally, it ["specifies a base path for resolving relative URLs to assets such as images, scripts, and style sheets,"](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#the-base-tag) namely your Angular distribution. Since `<base href>` is just a HTML element, you can see the [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base) for details and see the [community wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889076/what-are-the-recommendations-for-html-base-tag) for implications.

If for some reason you fall into the above two exceptions, you can provide the `APP_BASE_HREF` instead, which is solely used for routing purposes (using the `PathLocationStrategy`) and does not set or interact with the `<base href>`.

### Summary

1. `<base href>` is used as the base URL for routing when `APP_BASE_HREF` is NOT set.
2. Setting a combination of `<base href>` and `APP_BASE_HREF` can be used for deployment scenarios in which the displayed URL and actual location where files are being served are different.
3. In the case you [don't have access to the `index.html`, the `APP_BASE_HREF` must be set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40274540/chrome-extension-no-base-href-set-please-provide-a-value-for-the-app-base-hre) if using the `PathLocationStrategy`.

### Further reading

- https://angular.io/guide/router#base-href-1
- https://angular.io/guide/deployment#the-base-tag
- https://angular.io/api/common/APP_BASE_HREF
- https://angular.io/api/common/PathLocationStrategy#description

Answer (score 0):

@ahong's answer is spot on however I would like to explain the difference with an example:

Consider you have an app with a route `/page1` hosted on `mysite.com`

without setting any of these your site shows the page at route `mysite.com/page1`.

**APP_BASE_HREF**

If you want to have some prefix to the page route, then you set that in APP_BASE_HREF. Then your app will route your page as mysite.com/*your-app-base-href-value*/page1

**--base-href or -br**

this is where your app will load the assets from. When it needs to download a chuck `xyz.js` then it will fetch it from your server mysite.com/*your-base-href-value*/xyz.js
note this is not related to the frontend routing that you see for page1, but for the assets and is useful if you deploy your dist in a subfolder on your web server