Angular 17 - wrong use of deployUrl
I have a question concerning use of  deploy url configuration : https://angular.io/guide/deployment#the-deploy-url
I think I am mixing baseHref and deployUrl and I would be grateful to have some help with that.
I am actually deploying an Angular 17.3.5 application on an Nginx server with Docker
I need my application route having a prefix "/prefix" (https://localhost/prefix/my-routes)
Firstly, I handled this providing a base href like this :
{
    provide: APP_BASE_HREF,
    useValue: '/prefix/',
},

But I found out that my assets and styles set up in my angular.json :
"assets": [
  "src/favicon.ico",
  "src/assets"
],
"styles": [
  "src/styles/styles.scss",
  "src/styles/source/tailwind.css"
],

are still set without the prefix : https://localhost/favicon.ico for exemple
That's when I tried to use deployUrl configuration in angular.json configuration :
"deployUrl": "/prefix/",

But assets and styles are still accessible without prefix :  https://localhost/favicon.ico
It seems I'm missing something about this configuration, but I don't see this.
Thanks in advance for the help ! 
EDIT - FIXED
Finally, I didn't use deployUrl

I used APP_BASE_HREF to let know Angular router that all my routes will have a prefix /prefix/

I added in my index.html


  <base href="/prefix/">


I made sure every call to my assets where made on relative path

    <use [attr.xlink:href]="'./assets/..."></use>

instead of
    <use [attr.xlink:href]="'/assets/..."></use>




.class {
    background: url('../../../assets/...');
}

instead of
.class {
    background: url('/assets/...');
}


the basehRef is related to how Angular mannage the router (not related about the directories of your application). when the basehref is, e.g. /prefix/ a direction like /prefix/home search in router the component related to /home. In general you don't use a provider BASE-HRef to change else, when you "transpile" using ng build you indicate the base-href: ng build --base-href prefix

in most case you don't need to set deployUrl nor APP_BASE_HREF.
You want to build your app with the --base-href yourPrefix
this will add the base href in the generated index.html file.
yourPrefix will be the prefix for all your assets, this means that also the folder structure on the server should be /yourPrefix/theAssets

APP_BASE_HREF is the equivalent of --base-href parameter in build command or baseHref  parameter in angular.json configuration
The prefix is not added in the folder sructure on the server
This is why I'm asking for your help
Do you see something in my configuration not matching the expected ?
What is the use of deployUrl then ?

accordingly to this post, APP_BASE_HREF is not the same as base-href.
As I understand it, APP_BASE_HREF only affect the routing and not static assets:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69094451/what-is-the-difference-between-html-base-href-and-angular-app-base-href

Ok my bad , my mistake was to think it was the same thing. Thank you
